# PHP & MySQL, what's returned when the query yields no rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little confused about something in the PHP interface to MySQL.  The documentation for mysql_query (used to execute commands and queries) says this for return values:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(),
>   and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the
>   returned data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a
>   SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows
>   were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not
>   have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

I understand that I can call mysql_num_rows to get a count of the returned rows from a query assuming I did a command in the {SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN} set.

Aside from that though... what happens if a query in that set executes successfully (database wise) but returns no result rows?  Does mysql_query return true or false in that case (i.e. is this a failure condition)?  What's the best way to check for the "no results" possibility of a successful query using this interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would fall into the case of the first part of the documentation:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

A query that returns no result rows will return neither `true`, nor `false`, but a resource object.

However, the resource object will have no rows, i.e., `mysql_num_rows()` will return `0` and the first call to `mysql_fetch_*` will return `FALSE`.  There are a number of ways that you can detect this situation, but calling `mysql_num_rows()` is probably one of the easiest.

Comment: @Johan: It won't return `true`.

Answer (score 2):

not sure its best way but i generally use mysql_num_rows to check for the result resource and if

```
$countt = mysql_num_rows($resource);
if($count>0)
{
//do further
}
```

like this in this case.

Answer (score 1):

to see what it returns, 
use

```html
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  customers WHERE phone = $phoneNum", $link);
  
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

     echo $count;
```